# Get a filter array in days with momentjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, momentjs

I have an array with almost 1000 date values. I want to create a new array but only with the dates that correspond to Monday. I'm trying to do with momentjs but i don't understand very well how can I do it.

```
const mondayArray = [];
        for (let e = 0; e<deliveries.length;e++)
        {
          let objects = deliveries[e];
          if(objects.date===(moment(objects.date).day(1))){
            mondayArray.push(objects);
          }
        }
```

My main array is deliveries and it has a parameter called date. I tried to looping through the array and checking each value to create the new array with only the corresponding values. But I receive the same original array with the same values.

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `filter` method on `deliveries`.

If I understand you data structure correctly, you can try :

```js
const mondayArray = deliveries.filter(d => d.date.day() === 1);
```